# Django: How to get American date format in a form?

Tags: django

For some reason the American date format is not accepted in my form. I wonder if any Django developer from US could help me with this. I suspect the timezone in the settings also affect the date format, but I am not sure.

**Settings:**

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

**ModelForm:**

```
class CallsForm(ModelForm):    
   class Meta:
        model = Conversation   
        widgets = {
                    'contact_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Add the date...', 'id': 'datepicker', 'class': 'placeholder_fix_css'}, format='%m/%d/%Y'),
                   }
```

[image]

Any idea? thanks

**Update:**

I came a step closer to what is happening:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)
```

It seems as soon as the LocaleMiddleware is loaded, Django gets the settings from my  browser session, Hence the dateformat is changed to European reflect my location. Clever.

Now that the date input is accepted in American dateformat.
Within the template I get `Aug. 31, 2012`, which is also correct.
However in the forms, once I try to modify the record I get `2012-08-31` ??

That doesn't seem right. Sure I could use `format='%m/%d/%Y'` to override it, but isn't that hardcoded and bad practice?  Surely the forms have to rely on the current culture's date formatting, that is American, but why isn't that happening?

Comment: The default date format of your db is `YYYY-MM-DD` the localization is on the form field _input validation_ not on display. You'll need to make sure its localized per the user's current selected locale when used in templates or when output (as in, when you pre-fill a form's field).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
class CallsForm(ModelForm):
   contact_date = DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Add the date...', 'id': 'datepicker', 'class': 'placeholder_fix_css'}, format='%m/%d/%Y'))    
   class Meta:
        model = Conversation
```

Comment: it throws an exception: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats'`

Comment: this works now. Thank you. However is this not violating the localization of the application when hardcoding input formats? Shouldn't the date format be selected by Django framwork depending on the selected language/culture?

Comment: @Kave Actually you don't need to specify input_formats above since Django has a suitable default in place. As for Localization you can look into setting the field's localize parameter to True. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#format-localization

Comment: Ahhh I came a step closer. Please see updated question. Many Thanks

Comment: Ahh I found the solution. Its much more involving. I will post the answer soon. Your solution is part of it though. :)

Comment: That's great! I look forward to seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!! Hi Kave, after some time looking into your problem, finally I have found a solution.

- First of all, you should use activate( language_code ) to switch to new language.
- You must set as localized both: field and widget:

Sample switch language:

```
def display_current_language(request):
    if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en-gb':
        lang = "You prefer to read British English {code}.".format(
                  code=request.LANGUAGE_CODE )
        activate(request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
    elif request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en-us':
        lang = "You prefer to read American English {code}.".format(
                  code=request.LANGUAGE_CODE )
        activate('en-us')    
    else:
        lang = "You prefer to read Deutsch {code}.".format( 
                   code=request.LANGUAGE_CODE )
        activate(request.LANGUAGE_CODE)    
    return lang
```

Sample using your model (company) and your field ( date ):

```
class CompanyForm(ModelForm):        
    class Meta:
        model = Company 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CompanyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date'].localize = True
        self.fields['date'].widget.is_localized = True
```

Posted also in '[Django: despite selected language, Forms still rely on LANGUAGE_CODE to format datetime (demo included)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956576/django-despite-selected-language-forms-still-rely-on-language-code-to-format-d)' post.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, now to the solution to this problem.  It has been a great team work to get that far. :)

As solartic mentioned below the localize parameter for the field within the form must be set to true.  If its a ModelForm it will be a bit more tricky, as you need a callback:

```
class CompanyForm(ModelForm):
    def date_callback(self, field, **kwargs) :
        return field.date(localize=True, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
```

But this is not enough. Without hardcoding any date-input formats, it is required to override the `formats.py`.  This is a bit complicated, see [Creating custom format files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files)  I have created a demo to this [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44307777/Sandbox.zip).

The demo works only half-way, as switching the languages works only for the template but not for the form. In order to solve this you need the solution of danihp. :)
The language needs to be activated again, once switched.  For his full fix see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956576/django-despite-selected-language-forms-still-rely-on-language-code-to-format-d#comment15966386_11956576)

It has been a great team effort to solve this. :)

I hope this helps someone out there...