# Django: despite selected language, Forms still rely on LANGUAGE_CODE to format datetime (demo included)

Tags: django, datetime, localization, internationalization

I have created a small demo to show the problem.

When you click on British English, you can see how both the date- and time format change accordingly, which is great.

Now if you click on Add, you will see how both the current date and time are populated for you.  However they still carry the American date format, instead of the selected British language.

The only way to fix this is to change `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'` to `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'` in settings.py. This approach would be obviously useless as its no longer dynamic and favors one group over the other. This should be the last priority since the selected language should have a higher priority.

I have created custom `formats.py` to override the date and time formats for `en` and `en_GB` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files) so I am clueless what else I could do.

Please be so kind and download my demo (22 kb) from [my dropbox](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44307777/Sandbox.zip): 
All you have to do is to edit settings.py and adjust the path to sqlite.db.

Have I overlooked something or is this a Django bug?

Comment: Have you tried with [activate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.activate)?

Comment: Alright, I just added this to my AddView() `language = translation.get_language_from_request(request)
    translation.activate(language)`  I can see how en-gb is activated, without any effect. :(

Comment: Have you find something? I'm working with your code unsuccessfully.

Comment: I think this is a bug. I leave it until tomorrow and if no one knows anything, I will report it to the team. :(  Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: Hi have, I have make test until now. I don't know why date is not displayed according first DATE_INPUT_FORMATS item. I have changed format by hand: `self.fields['date'].widget.format = '%d/%m/%Y'`

Comment: and also `self.fields['date'].input_formats = ['%d/%m/%Y']`. I have my own translation system because customer must translate app (translation is stored in database), I will include date format into translation system. Regards!

Comment: Thanks Dani, that would be a workaround doing it in code according to the selected language. But its not really a nice solution and un-django like. :) I translate the app into several languages for the customers and the if-conditionals would grow this way rapidly. :(

Comment: Yes, is a dirty approach also you should remember to write it for each form ... .Please, let me know the final solution. Also, have you test activate in `display_current_language,  activate(request.LANGUAGE_CODE)` ? This is the right place (I have tested it in your code unsuccessfully)

Comment: Kate, I'm working with your code to isolate problem. Making some changes in your code app runs as expected. Changes are: generate form with `modelform_factory` and add activate in `display_current_language`: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0FWI

Comment: WoW you found a workaround!!! Can't believe this. It is a hack but it works haha. Its interesting how you do `activate('en-us')`. I can see `en-gb` and `en` are listed as supported languages, but funny enough I couldn't see `en-us` in the list. So I ended up using just `en` as you can see in my code.  Is it possible to set proper US english in `LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('US English')),
    ('en-gb', ugettext('British English')),
)` ?

Comment: You will be more happy now. I have found final solution ;)

Comment: I have found `en-us` in [translate source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py): `Turns a language name (en-us) into a locale name (en_US)...`

Comment: @danihp Look at this here, `en-us` is not even in the list of supported languages. How strange...When I try to set `en-us` in LANGUAGES in settings I get an error: `Unknown language code 'en-us'.` : https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!! Hi Kave, after some time looking into your problem, finally I have found a solution.

- First of all, you should use activate( language_code ) to switch to new language.
- You must set as localized both: field and widget:

Sample switch language:

```
def display_current_language(request):
    if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en-gb':
        lang = "You prefer to read British English {code}.".format(
                  code=request.LANGUAGE_CODE )
        activate(request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
    elif request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en-us':
        lang = "You prefer to read American English {code}.".format(
                  code=request.LANGUAGE_CODE )
        activate('en-us')    
    else:
        lang = "You prefer to read Deutsch {code}.".format( 
                   code=request.LANGUAGE_CODE )
        activate(request.LANGUAGE_CODE)    
    return lang
```

Sample using your model (company) and your field ( date ):

```
class CompanyForm(ModelForm):        
    class Meta:
        model = Company 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CompanyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date'].localize = True
        self.fields['date'].widget.is_localized = True
```

Comment: +1 Thanks again for not giving up on this problem. :) Just an additional info: I haven't changed my CompanyForm and it still works. The solution is the `display_current_language()`. Yes you need `localize=True`, but `widget.is_localized = True` seems to be not necessary. But wouldn't harm I guess. :)