# Determine the 4 digit date to save if a 2 digit date is input

Tags: django, validation, date, localization, formatting

I've added a `formats.py` file to my django project to set the date format to display dd/mm/yyyy throughout the application.

However people must be able to enter a date as d/m/yy also. If you were to enter 1/1/49 django saves this as 01/01/2049. How does it decide I meant 2049 and not 1949?

I want to be able to control this, without having to write out validation for something it seem Django does already.

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956576/django-despite-selected-language-forms-still-rely-on-language-code-to-format-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a POSIX and ISO C standard which Python inherited, and in turn Django: values 69–99 are mapped to 1969–1999, and values 0–68 are mapped to 2000–2068. It is not configurable short of writing your own.

Comment: Right thank you. Would you need a clean method to detect and correctly set something like in my example then so that it doesn't incorrectly set a 4 digit date after 2 digit input?