# Change the format of DateTimePicker dynamically for Django form

Tags: python, django, datetimepicker

The format changes when I change the site language. '%d/%m/%Y' changes to '%m/%d/%Y'. So I can't save the information in the form to the database.

**Example:**

'%d/%m/%Y'(24.11.2003) as save in Turkish. But I get an error when I want to update in English. Because format changes as '%m/%d/%Y'(11.24.2003).

It is my forms.

forms.py

```
'date1': DatePickerInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'),
'date2': DatePickerInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'),
```

Comment: Check this [blog](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/03/how-to-use-date-picker-with-django.html), it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956576/django-despite-selected-language-forms-still-rely-on-language-code-to-format-d) is appropriate for my problem. I tried but I couldn't figure it out.

As a temporary solution;

**settings.py**

*Before:*

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('tr', _('Turkish')),
    ('en',_('English')),)
```

*After:*

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('tr', _('Turkish')),
    ('en-gb',_('English')),)
```